# Qt thread makes the Qt Creator no respond for a while

Tags: qt, qthread

I have a simple project on the demo of QThread using QtCreator4.5 and Qt5.7. In the project, three pushbuttons, `threadA`, `threadB` and `quit`, are created. My intention is to print `A` and `B` in the console when the `threadA` and `threadB` are clicked respectively, and the application is to be quitted when '`quit`' is pressed.

Here is `mythread.h`:

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QString>

class mythread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    mythread();
    void setMessage(const QString &message);
    void stop();

protected:
    void run();

private:
    QString messageStr;
    volatile bool stopped;
};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

The `mythread.cpp`:

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include <iostream>

mythread::mythread()
{
    stopped = false;
}

void mythread::setMessage(const QString &message)
{
    messageStr = message;
}

void mythread::stop()
{
    stopped = true;
}

void mythread::run()
{
    while(!stopped)
        std::cout<<qPrintable(messageStr);
    stopped = false;
    std::cout<< std::endl;
}
```

The mainwindow.cpp is:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_threadA_clicked()
{
    mythreadA.start();
    mythreadA.setMessage("A");
}

void MainWindow::on_threadB_clicked()
{
    mythreadB.start();
    mythreadB.setMessage("B");
}

void MainWindow::on_quit_clicked()
{
    mythreadA.stop();
    mythreadB.stop();
    MainWindow::close();
}
```

When I run the project, the printed results are displayed in the Application Output of the QtCreator, not in an external prompt console. Quitting the application makes QtCreator no respond for a while, but finally restore to normal. It seems that the threads are still running when the application is quitted.

Comment: MainWindow::close();????

Comment: @eyllanesc: is that something wrong?

Comment: Yes, change `MainWindow::close();` to `close();`

Comment: @eyllanesc: there is no much difference. The QtCreator will still be 'no responding' for a while when quitted. Probably, I need to create a console application.

Comment: Change `while(!stopped)
        std::cout<<qPrintable(messageStr);` to `while(!stopped){
        std::cout<<qPrintable(messageStr); QThread::msleep(10); }`

Comment: eyllanesc: The solution is to redirect your output to the console and not QtCreator or remove std::cout from the while. I wouldn't know another reason why QtCreator could hang. Even if you block the application's main thread with an infinite sleep QtCreator would just work fine.  He wrote in the SO question `When I run the project, the printed results are displayed in the Application Output of the QtCreator, `

Comment: What do you mean when you say creator becomes unresponsive? Does the UI freeze or does it just take a while to print that the application has finished while the UI is responsive?

Comment: Before quitting the application, the creator Application Output keeps giving results normally, but when quitted, the creator IDE becomes frozen for  minutes and then restores to the normal.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and there is nothing wrong with Qt Creator that is not frozen.

However, as your code is written, your threads are probably still running when you quit the application. Moreover, the private member `stopped` should be protected by a mutex, as `volatile` won't do this job.

To protect your private variable `stopped` with a mutex, you can use for example `QMutexLocker` in the following way :

```
void MyThread::stop() // called by the GUI Thread
{
    const QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
    stopped = true;
}
```

and to read the value of the boolean :

```
bool MyThread::isStopped // called by run()
{
    const QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
    return stopped;
}
```

Finally to ensure that the threads are properly finished when you press the quit button :

```
void MainWindow::on_quit_clicked()
{
    mythreadA.stop();
    mythreadB.stop();
    myThreadA.wait(); 
    myThreadB.wait();
    this->close(); // close the main application
}
```